# Running sbt results in "com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse;1.4.0: not found"

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm running Windows 7 x64 cygwin.

I just installed the latest sbt for Martin Odersky's Coursera Scala class after a previous version was installed about a year ago.  First I tried removing the old version and using the msi installer.  It returned the below error upon running `sbt` from an empty directory.

Later I tried uninstalling the msi version and manually installing the (latest) `sbt-launch.jar` file and calling it from the old script.  I got the same error.

Any ideas what's wrong?  Is there an sbt plugins directory somewhere that could be causing this?

```
~/dummy > sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Jeff\.sbt\plugins
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/Jeff/.sbt/plugins/}default-46e191...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse;1.4.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse;1.4.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Jeff\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.sbteclipse\sbteclipse\scala_2.9.2\sbt_0.12\1.4.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbteclipse/sbteclipse_2.9.2_0.12/1.4.0/sbteclipse-1.4.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#actions;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#interface;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#io;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#control;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.9.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#completion;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#collections;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#api;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logging;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#process;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compile;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#persist;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.9.0;0.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-rc1 ...
[info] Resolving com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.46 ...
[info] Resolving commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient;3.1 ...
[info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#command;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_0-m4;0.12.0 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse;1.4.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse:1.4.0 (sbtVersion=0.12, scalaVersion=2.9.2)
[warn]
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse;1.4.0: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:211)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:102)
        at sbt.IvySbt.liftedTree1$1(Ivy.scala:49)
        at sbt.IvySbt.action$1(Ivy.scala:49)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:58)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:99)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:95)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:114)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:949)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:947)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$54.apply(Defaults.scala:970)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$54.apply(Defaults.scala:968)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:972)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:967)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:975)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$45.apply(Defaults.scala:855)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$45.apply(Defaults.scala:852)
        at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
        at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
        at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
        at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse;1.4.0: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My older installation had an old version of the `sbteclipse` plugin installed.  I finally remembered that the `.sbt` directory on Windows is in the `C:\Users\[username]` folder.

Edit `build.sbt` file in the `C:\Users\[username]\plugins` folder and per the [sbtplugin page](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse#for-the-impatient), replace the `addSbtPlugin` line with:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

Comment: I have the same problem. There is no \plugins folder in C:\Users\[username], and no build.sbt file anywhere on my system, so I'm still stuck.

Comment: @digitig create the `plugins` folder and `build.sbt` file yourself. They are not created automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you started sbt in the correct directory, i.e. progfun/example? Instead of the one that has confusingly been named progfun/example/project.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add :

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still runs into this error just try the following.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse"%"sbteclipse-plugin"%"5.2.4")
```

Note that the version of the `sbteclipse-plugin` is now 5.2.4 and not 5.1.0. For future reference, just update to the latest version of `sbteclipse-plugin`.